# official GitHub identicon algorithm

Tags: github, identicon

I want to get the official GitHub implementation of the identicon algorithm.
Where can i find that? Thank you.

I've found a lot of tutorials. but they all are not the official implementation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in an answer of [this Twitter Post](https://mobile.twitter.com/chkesp/status/995853640836366336), **there is no official release** but an [employee of GitHub](https://web.archive.org/web/20200508154207/https://github.com/dgraham) ported it to rust and published it [here](https://github.com/dgraham/identicon). The number from that you need to enter there is the id of your user. You can get it by running a request to `https://api.github.com/users/<username>` (the field is named `id`).

After building it, you can test it using the following command (bash, `$ghUserId`):

```
echo -n "$ghUserId" | ./target/debug/identicon > identicon.png
```

In order to get the user id from the username and calculate the identicon in one command, you can use this (if you have installed `jq`, `$githubUserName` is a variable with the user name):

```
curl "https://api.github.com/users/$githubUserName" | jq .id | ./target/debug/identicon > identicon.png
```

Also note that I used `./target/debug/identicon` as the executable as I found it here after building it.

You can also get the identicon from `https://github.com/identicons/<username>.png` as stated in [this blog post](https://github.blog/2013-08-14-identicons/).

Comment: wow thank you @dan1st . I am also making project on it. Thank you :).
but i am afraid those stackoverflow havent also opensourced their identicon generation algorithm . But anyway :)

Comment: Nice to hear that but I think that a port from an official employee works good, too.